# how can i return null when dividing values

Tags: oracle

I would like to get a null value when i SUM UP and divide multiple values in event any of the values that i am summing up has a null. in the example below i would like the return value to be be a null if any of the values i am summing up have a null or zero.

```
(((CAST (NVL(XYY.SCR,NULL)AS NUMBER) - 57.81114) / 24.79211) + ((CAST(NVL(WPM_SCR,NULL)AS NUMBER) - 40.7836082505127) / 17.5946375921401) + ((CAST (NVL(SLOT3,NULL) AS NUMBER) - 50.204190919674 ) / 25.5100093808846) ) / 3 BASE
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplified example:

- anything `+ null` or `/ null` will be null anyway, so you don't have to do anything about it
- for `+ 0` or `/ 0`, use `CASE` (see lines #7 and #11)

---

```
SQL> with test (a, b) as
  2    (select 6, 3 from dual union all
  3     select 5, 0 from dual union all
  4     select 2, null from dual
  5    )
  6  select a, b,
  7    case when b = 0 then null
  8         else a/b
  9    end result_div,
 10    --
 11    case when a = 0 or b = 0 then null
 12         else a + b
 13    end result_sum
 14  from test;

         A          B RESULT_DIV RESULT_SUM
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         6          3          2          9
         5          0
         2

SQL>
```

Comment: I wanted to use the above code.Problem is when  some of the values i am summing up are null its not returning null as expected.

Comment: Well, you misused the NVL function. It is to be used when some values are NULL and you want to return something that's different from NULL. There's no use in `NVL(something, NULL)`, just doesn't make sense. As I said: anything + NULL is NULL. If you got different result, then those values aren't NULL.

Comment: Basically, i wanted cases where there might be a null or a zero in te values i am summing up to return me a null so that when i  divide the null with a number i get a null

Comment: Then use CASE as my example shows. Once again: anything added to NULL, divided by NULL, multiplied by NULL - everything **will** be NULL, you don't have to do anything about it.